# Why do I get "A cursor with the name already exists"?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-cursor

I have this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER CHECKINGMAXQTYDAYSVACANCY
    ON TDINCI
AFTER INSERT 
AS
    DECLARE
        @incidentCode int,
        @dateStart datetime,
        @dateEnd datetime,
        @daysAccumulated int,
        @maxDaysAvailable int

    set @daysAccumulated = 0;

    select @incidentCode = CO_INCI from inserted;
    select @maxDaysAvailable = IN_DIAS_GANA from TCINCI
        where CO_INCI = @incidentCode;

    declare detailsCursor CURSOR FOR
        select FE_INIC, FE_FINA from TDINCI
        where CO_INCI = @incidentCode;

    open detailsCursor;
    
    if CURSOR_STATUS('variable', 'detailsCursor') >= 0
    begin
        fetch next from detailsCursor
            into @dateStart, @dateEnd;

        while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        begin
            set @daysAccumulated = @daysAccumulated + (DATEDIFF(DAY, @dateStart, @dateEnd) + 1);

            fetch next from detailsCursor
            into @dateStart, @dateEnd;
        end
        close detailsCursor;
        deallocate detailsCursor;
    end
    IF(@maxDaysAvailable > @daysAccumulated)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR ('No se pueden ingresar mas dias de los programados en la cabecera de incidencias.', 16, 1);
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
        RETURN 
    END
GO
```

When I do a Insert to the table TDINCI

```
INSERT INTO TDINCI 
VALUES (1, '20150101', '20150115', '2015-2015')
```

I get an error:

> A cursor with the name 'detailsCursor' already exists.

I open

```
open detailsCursor;
```

and close the cursor.

```
close detailsCursor;
deallocate detailsCursor;
```

Maybe there is something with the scope of cursor that I don't manage?

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` will each contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? select @incidentCode = CO_INCI from inserted;` - it's non-deterministic - one will be picked all other **ignored**. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account! Also: ***please avoid cursors*** - especially inside a trigger!!!!!!!!

Comment: If you still decide to use cursors, you should really check the declare cursor options, at least local, read only, forward_only / fast_forward

Comment: @marc_s If I can't use cursors how would fetch all the data in inserted table:
I was doing something like:
`DECLARE ALLDATAINSERTED CURSOR LOCAL FOR
 select * from inserted;`

Comment: @ErickAstoOblitas: use a **set-based** approach - use `INSERT INTO ....  SELECT ....` or something like that - don't do RBAR (row-by-agonizing-row) processing - ***especially*** not in a trigger!!

Answer (score 141, accepted):

You are using global cursor that will be defined each time you are calling this procedure and give you the same error.

Define a local cursor. Just put the keyword `LOCAL` after `CURSOR`:

```
declare detailsCursor CURSOR LOCAL FOR
...
```

Comment: what is the difference ?